# Angular: Event Emitter not received

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a service with an EventEmitter that gets fired if the data changes.

```
@Output() reservationChangedEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

public notifyReservationsChanged() {
        this.reservationChangedEvent.emit({});
    }
```

That the data changes is triggered by a modal that is started from a controller.

In my controller I subscribe for those events:

```
ngOnInit() {
        ...
        this.reservationService.reservationChangedEvent.subscribe(() => this.reloadData());
    }
```

My problem is that I can not receive events in my overview component. If I subscribe for events (for checking) in my service or my modal I do receive them.

Any idea why the overview controller can not receive events?

Comment: this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/event) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
@Output() reservationChangedEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

to:

```
reservationChangedSubject = new Subject<any>();
reservationChangedEvent = this.reservationChangedSubject.asObservable()
```

and this:

```
public notifyReservationsChanged() {
    this.reservationChangedEvent.emit({});
}
```

to:

```
public notifyReservationsChanged() {
    this.reservationChangedSubject.next({});
}
```

Comment: are your sure? Property next does not exist on type Observable<any>

Comment: You should call next() on Subject ofc. Fixed.

Comment: did that but nothing changes. Is this.reservationService.reservationChangedEvent.subscribe(() => this.reloadData()); still correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, please check notifyReservationsChanged().

Comment: Yes it is the same.

Comment: It has to work, here is example of using Subject: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154895/discussion-between-michal-ochocinski-and-netshark1000).

Answer (score 0):

`@Output()` and `EventEmitter` are meant to be used only in components, not in services.

For services, you should use `Subject` instead.

Your service should contain:

```
private reservationChangedSource = new Subject<any>();
reservationChanged$ = this.reservationChangedSource.asObservable();

notifyReservationsChanged() {
    this.reservationChangedEvent.next({});
}
```

In your component:

```
reservationChangeSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.reservationChangeSubscription = this.reservationService.reservationChanged$
        .subscribe(() => this.reloadData());
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.reservationChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```